# change UIButton text with another UIButton text (swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uibutton

My question is how to change `UIButton`'s title with another `UIButton`'s title.
I have three buttons and I want to exchange title for button 1 and 3 with each other when I click on button 2.

Look at this image and you will understand.

how can I do that?

[image]

Comment: can you show your code

Comment: Why don't you just declare variable to store, and then change the text?

Comment: @EICaptain NO I do not know how to do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's very simple.

Just preserve one of the text from button in a String and replace it by clicking on a button.

```
let title1 = btn1.titleLabel!.text

btn1.setTitle(btn2.titleLabel!.text, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
btn2.setTitle(title1, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

[image]

Learn and apply the code!
Hope it helps you.

Comment: and what if I click button 2 one more time? nothing will happen

Comment: @J.S.O you have to consider the toggle button as third button. you have to understand the code.

Comment: sorry I do not understand

Comment: @J.S.O Check the image. Code work fine. Just add it to 3rd button click

Comment: @J.S.O Great. Welcome anytime :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
let title1 = button1.currentTitle!
button1.setTitle(button3.currentTitle!, forState: .Normal)
button3.setTitle(title1, forState: .Normal)
```

Comment: and what if I click button 2 one more time? nothing will happen

Comment: it'll still switch the titles.

Answer (score 1):

Try using below snippet, you will change/toggle button1 and button3 title on click of button2.(Whatever title they have)

```
@IBAction func btn2Tapped(btn2 : UIButton)
{
    var strBtnTittle : String!

    if (btn2.selected)
    {
        btn2.selected=false
        strBtnTittle = btn1.titleLabel?.text
        btn1.setTitle(btn3.titleLabel?.text, forState: .Normal)
        btn3.setTitle(strBtnTittle, forState: .Normal)

    }
    else
    {
        btn2.selected=true
        strBtnTittle = btn3.titleLabel?.text
        btn3.setTitle(btn1.titleLabel?.text, forState: .Normal)
        btn1.setTitle(strBtnTittle, forState: .Normal)
    }
}
```